# Выравнивание CSS3 - display: grid

Tags: css, html5, css-grid

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выровнять мои ромбы лесенкой?
это моё первое знакомство с гридами, но никак не пойму, как сдвинут как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background-color: #f6f8fb;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 375px 375px 375px;
  grid-auto-rows: 187px;
  align-self: center;
}

.grid a:last-child {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}
.grid a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e2e4e7;
  width: 235px;
  height: 235px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #444444;
  border: 15px solid #f6f8fb;
  outline: 1px solid #e2e4e7;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.grid a:hover{
  background-color: #3e9eff;
}
.grid a img {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.4);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.4);
}
.grid a span {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 66%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #f6f8fb;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="grid">
            <a href="#"><span>LOREM</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>LOREM</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>LOREM</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>LOREM</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>LOREM</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>LOREM</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы делал примерно вот так, лучше повернуть саму сетку.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f6f8fb;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.grid__item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.grid__item:first-child {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.c-elem {
  position: relative;
  width: 235px;
  height: 235px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.c-elem:hover {
  background-color: #3e9eff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="c-elem"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="c-elem"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="c-elem"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="c-elem"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="c-elem"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="c-elem"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: оо, я даже не подумал об этом, спасибо!! а не подскажите еще как можно сделать такие линии сетки как на картинке? (выходящие за границы ромба, на нужную длину)

Comment: H4nteR, добавьте линий через ::after и ::before